# SSRS - Repeat column headers during export to PDF

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report that I want to export to PDF. However, some cells in the tablix are bigger than one single pdf page. 
The table header is only shown when a new cell is on top of the pdf page. If it is a continuation from a prior cell from the page before, the header is not repeated.
When I preview the report, the report is only 1 of 1 pages long. However, once exported, it comes down to 7 pages.
Any idea how to solve this issue? I want to see the header on every page, regardless if the cell fits on one page or not.
I have already set the first Static Row group to the following attributes:
    `FixedData` = True
    `KeepWithGroup` = After
    `RepeatOnNewPage` = True
On the tablix I have set the following attributes:
`FixedColumnHeaders` = False
`FixedRowHeaders` = False

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Does the export have to be to PDF? If you export to Excel then it is simple to handle once you have exported?

Comment: No, unfortunately it needs to be pdf since I need to email it out through subscription once it is created. I cannot email Excel.

Comment: If you export to excel and then: Go to Page Layout in the top ribbon. Click print Titles. Click in to the ‘Rows to repeat at top’ box. Click on the row you want to freeze. Click OK. Export to PDF. It means you have to use Excel, but you end up with a PDF report with headers at the top of each page.

Comment: Right, but that means that I have to manually intervene every time. And the report is created and send each night.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. The user will just have to live with it. Thank you for looking in to it though. Daniel

Comment: @Daniel227 you mentioned it has to be PDF since it will be emailed on a subscription. But excel spreadsheets can also be emailed on ssrs subscriptions and can even be embedded on a web view (which can then be made onto a PDF by the user)

Comment: @DLPDev thanks! However, the user is not supposed to receive anything but pdf. So him converting it to pdf after he received the Excel version is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no solution to this if you are exporting directly to PDF.